# Responsive vertical alignment of text and button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, text, alignment

I'm having some trouble ensuring my text and bootstrap button stay in the vertical middle of my bootstrap row as the screen size reduces/expands. There must be an easy way to achieve this...

```
<div class="cta-promo">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-8">
        <p class="cta-promo-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent posuere pharetra rhoncus. Sed et lorem vehicula, tincidunt quam at, pharetra nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus eget mollis magna, a fermentum mauris. Mauris orci neque, egestas nec diam nec, vestibulum vestibulum nibh.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-1 col-md-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3">
        <button>Apply for this today</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/74vsr332/

The text is hidden on xs view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in Bootstrap you can combine `Flexbox` and media queries and add rule when `min-width: 768` because you are using `sm` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/74vsr332/1/)

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great Nenad. Thanks. Is this compatible across browsers?

Comment: It seems as usual there might be issues in IE with this solution...will need to do some testing.